# Popup window blocked debug mode

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Periodically, when mouse over variable in debug mode, popup blocks further work. Only restart helps.
How resolve this bug? Maybe disable pop up window at all?

Answer (score 0):

probably it has been fixed today at http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/105261

If you are working on Mac or Windows you can check the fixed version in Canary build.
Otherwise you have to wait until it get included into dev and other builds.